# Why "wanted" is not "latest"?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using `npm outdated -g --depth=0` to see which globally installed packages have newer version. I am getting this:

```
$ npm outdated -g --depth=0
Package              Current   Wanted     Latest  Location
bower                  1.6.8    1.6.8      1.7.1
jshint                 2.8.0    2.8.0  2.9.1-rc2
jspm                 0.16.13  0.16.13    0.16.19
npm-windows-upgrade    1.0.1    1.0.1      1.2.0
typescript             1.7.3    1.7.3      1.7.5
```

I can not update any of those packages. `npm update -g` does nothing. Why `Wanted` field is has lower version than `Latest`? I am using windows 7, node 4.2.1 and npm 3.5.2

Comment: I suspect "Wanted" means "Minimum version wanted", which means "Minimum version required".

Comment: i guess it means minimum stable version as of now .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are global packages there is no package.json to direct their update policy. By default "wanted" version is the same as installed or "current" for global packages. That means `npm update` will not update them saying that they are at the most recent wanted version.

In order to update them use `npm -g install ...`. Install will use "latest" version from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

`npm update -g` shouldn't do "nothing" -- you should try `npm update -g --verbose` and see what that has to say.

I've had to run `npm update -g` a few times in succession to get it to update everything to the latest.

Comment: Those are global packages, and from what I know, they do not have package.json file(only local have).

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my answer to help with global packages.

Comment: I am getting bunch of: `not updating [package name] because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range` messages. Which make sense, but doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue and had a different solution not yet mentioned. My issue was that my package.json had semantic versioning constraints associated with versions. Given your package `bower`, for example, with a current/wanted version and of 1.6.8 and a latest version of 1.7.1, it could be possible that your `package.json` file shows:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bower": "~1.6",
}
```

Running `npm update bower` would not update bower past version 1.6 to version 1.7 because of the `~` prefix; to get around this you can run `npm install bower@latest` to bypass the semantic versioning constraints.